# My karate UI scripts run fine in my Mac but fails in a windows vm

Tags: karate

I developed karate UI automation scripts/features in my MAC. It's very stable and runs fine. I'm trying to setup Jenkins to trigger the same in a windows VM.

I was trying to manually run the script in windows VM but it keeps failing at different points each time I try.

The error is always 'javascript evaluation failed'

javascript evaluation failed: input(login.newPwd,pwd), failed to get reply for
javascript evaluation failed: retry().input(reg.add1,address), failed to get reply for: [id: 51, method: Input.dispatchKeyEvent, params: {modifier=0, type=keyUp, windowsVirtualKeyCode=79}]
javascript evaluation failed: retry().input(login.email,email), failed to get reply for: [id: 147, method: Input.dispatchKeyEvent, params: {modifier=0, type=keyUp, windowsVirtualKeyCode=72}]

The browser is Chrome. Any idea why this happens and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible bug. Can you try with version 0.9.6.RC4 and let us know, some work went into improving the key-handling.

Else can you kindly submit a way to replicate using this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/examples/ui-test

As a workaround, you can try switch to `chromedriver` on Windows and that should work. Would be great to confirm that from you as well.